# A chess board with numbers

Tags: mathematics, lateral-thinking, checkerboard

A 8x8 chess board is marked with the numbers from 1 to 64 sequentially from left to right, row by row and top to bottom.
Now a minus sign is added to 32 of those numbers such that in each row and in each column there are exactly 4 positive and 4 negative numbers. 
All 64 numbers are now added up.

What is the smallest sum, which can be achieved?

[image]

Comment: Smallest as in smallest absolute value (closest to zero) or absolute smallest (most negative number)?

Comment: I see what you did there with the second tag.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The smallest sum that can be achieved is

> $0$

Because

> This will always be the sum

Reasoning

> The entries in the $n$th row in the given grid may be written as $$\{8n -7, 8n -6, 8n-5, 8n-4, 8n-3, 8n -2, 8n-1, 8n \} $$ Notice that when we negate four entries in a single row and take the row sum, the parts containing $n$ all cancel out. Since the total sum is just the sum of row sums, the problem is thus equivalent to one in which each row is $$\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8\}$$ But, in this version of the problem, each column contains the same entry, so if we negate four entries in each column then the sum of the elements in each column is $0$ and hence, the overall sum is $0$

Answer (score 3):

This is one of the first on puzzling.SE that I can actually do! :)

There are many ways to get $0$.
Note that each row has precise $4$ or each $+/-$, so we can translate so that it's just eight copies of $\{1, ..., 8\}$.
By symmetry, we have
$$ 1 + 8 - 2 - 7 = 0
\quad\text{and}\quad
3+6 - 4-5 = 0.$$
So we can easily make each row sum to $0$.
Other combinations work.
Simply alternate these down each row, eg
\begin{matrix}
1 & -2 & -3 & 4 & 5 & -6 & -7 & 8 \\
-1 & 2 & 3 & -4 & -5 & 6 & 7 & -8 \\
1 & -2 & -3 & 4 & 5 & -6 & -7 & 8 \\
-1 & 2 & 3 & -4 & -5 & 6 & 7 & -8 \\
1 & -2 & -3 & 4 & 5 & -6 & -7 & 8 \\
-1 & 2 & 3 & -4 & -5 & 6 & 7 & -8 \\
1 & -2 & -3 & 4 & 5 & -6 & -7 & 8 \\
-1 & 2 & 3 & -4 & -5 & 6 & 7 & -8
\end{matrix}
There are loads of similar combinations.

Answer (score 1):

If the summation cannot be a negative number, the minimum sum that can be achieved is 0.
If the summation can be a negative number, then, the minimum that can be achieved is -107 (if the greatest numbers in each row is negated)

Comment: Each column must have 4 +s and 4 -s though too, so your latter suggestion doesn't fit.

Comment: @BenReinger: Say row 1 has 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 - the lowest sum can be achieved if the numbers are 1,2,3,4,-5,-6,-7,-8.. Similarly if all the largest numbers within every row are made negative numbers, the smallest sum is achieved. Which is -107.

Comment: @ManojBalu - remember you're not adding a row, but all 64 numbers

Comment: @ManojBalu more importantly (I think) remember there has to be 4(+) and 4(-) in each *column* besides each *row*